# Determining Optimal Data Period / Time Span for Model Training

Tags: optimization, overfitting, train, train-test-split, meteorology

I'm seeking advice on determining the ideal time span for optimizing a weather forecast strategy using historical data without overfitting/underfitting our model. In pursuit of optimal performance and highly accurate predictions in the upcoming month(s), what factors and methods should be considered when choosing the time span?

For instance, should the model be trained exclusively on the last month, or would a more extended period, such as the last 3 months, 6 months, or even a broader historical perspective spanning the last couple of years, be more effective?

It's worth mentioning that we have ample accurate data and abundant computational resources, so data availability and computational cost are not limiting factors. I appreciate insights into best practices and recommended techniques.